# Can I change all my installer dialogs' dimensions in one spot, using WiX?

Tags: wix

I'm building an installer using WiX and I want all my installer's dialogs to be larger than the default dimensions. Is there a central spot where I can set a width and height for all dialogs in my installer? If not, is there at least a way to change the built-in dialogs' dimensions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In WiX v3.6 you can use localization files to change size and location of dialogs and controls. See [my blog post](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2012/07/14/localizing-more-than-strings-in-wix-v3-6/) for details. It's still a lot of work to change everything.